# Operator calculations inside a Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Inside a Django template I have such a phrase:

```
<h4>{{ webinar.name or 'Not title' }}</h4>
```

leading to this error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: ' or 'Not title'' from 'webinar.name or 'Not title''
```

This is because Django does not like to calculate operators inside a template. It seems that [django-mathfilters](https://pypi.org/project/django-mathfilters/) does not have an `or` operator. I also do not like to use `{% if ... %}` either. Because this is a MWE. I have faced with other cases that I cannot get around them so easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<h4>{{ webinar.name|default:'Not title' }}</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Django does have operators inside templates but this won't work.

The easiest way to do this and keep you code clean is:

```
<h4>{% if webinar.name %}{{ webinar.name }}{% else %}No title{% endif %}</h4>
```